# How to clean/fix these bytes without string operations?

Tags: python

I have a `bytearray`, for example `[0x6B, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x6C]`.

For reasons out of my control the bytes are 'incorrect', and need to be fixed. The output I want is a `bytearray` like `[0xAB, 0xCD]`.

So in my example, I want to ignore the '6' part of the byte. (6 is just an example, it can change).

I'm currently doing this by:

1. Looping over pairs of bytes
2. Converting the bytes to a hex string, like `'6B6A'`
3. Taking the 4th and 2nd character of the string to build `'AB'`
4. Convert that `'AB'` hex string to a byte

I already have a solution that works but it feels 'wrong' to use string manipulation with numerical values.

I'm not proficient with bitwise operators and I'm not sure if I can use bitwise operators, or something else entirely, to do this in a faster and/or more efficient way.

Comment: The word I should have used was 'nibble', the first nibble is always junk and I want to ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the byte array 2 items at a time and use bit operations to combine the least significant 4 bits of each byte:

```
result = bytearray()
it = iter([0x6B, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x6C])
for a, b in zip(it, it):
    a &= 0x0F
    b = (b & 0x0F) << 4
    result.append(b|a)

>>> result
bytearray(b'\xab\xcd')
```

Or more succinctly as a list comprehension:

```
it = iter([0x6B, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x6C])
result = bytearray((b & 0x0F) << 4 | (a & 0x0F) for a, b in zip(it, it))
>>> result
bytearray(b'\xab\xcd')
```

Comment: I like the use of zip, it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is always the same you can do

```
l = [0x6B, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x6C]
packed = [k[0] & 0x0F | ((k[1] & 0x0F) << 4) for k in (l[c:c:+2] for c in range(0, len(l), 2))]
assert packed == [0xAB, 0xCD]
```

This will iterate over the pairs of bytes, use the lower nibble on the first byte as the lower nibble on the final byte and the upper nibble on the second byte as the upper nibble on the final byte.

Comment: Although not as readable (for me) as the other answers it is cool to see how compact it can be made.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that doesn't use bitwise operators.

If you know that the numbers are always in the range 0..255 (and they should if they are bytes), then you can get away with **multiplication** (instead of *shift-left*), **remainder** (instead of *bitwise-and*), and **sum** (instead of *bitwise-or*) operators:

```
input  = [0x6B, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x6C]
output = []

# Iterate in pairs
for i in range(0, len(input) / 2):
    # "High" nibble
    hi = input[2*i] % 16; # keep 4 least significant bits

    # "Low" nibble
    lo = input[2*i + 1] % 16; # keep 4 least significant bits

    # Multiply-by-16 is the same as shift-left-by-4
    # Sum is the same as bitwise-or (if the two operands have disjointed bits)
    output.append(hi * 16 + lo)

for byte in output:
    print format(byte, '02x')
```

Output:

```
ba
dc
```

Comment: Thanks for the word 'nibble' - I completely forgot about that! It would have helped in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

After a little trial and error:

To get `0x0B` from `0x6B`, I can do `0x6B & 0x0F`.

To get `0xA0` from `0x6A`, I can do the same as above, and then `result << 4`.

Then I can add these values together to produce `0xAB`.

Comment: Mine's not a full code complete answer, but now I understand the other answers better!